# sorting in p:datatable behave unusual

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using sorting in p:datatable, and last column is edit .
its working fine till sorting is pressed. as soon as I do sorting it behave unusual.
On editing it giving wrong object.
belwo is my datatable.

```
<h:form>
<h:inputHidden value="#{countryBean.initList}" />
    <p:dataTable id="existingCountry1" var="countryLang" value="#{countryBean.myexistingCountryList}" style="width: 100%" styleClass="role_detail_section" 
     rowStyleClass="activity_white, activity_blue"   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" rows="6" paginator="true">

        <p:column width="30%" headerText="Country " sortBy="countryName">
            <h:outputLabel value="${countryLang.countryName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="30%" headerText="Country Code " >
            <h:outputLabel value="${countryLang.countryCode}" />
        </p:column>


        <p:column  headerText="Edit" >

            <p:commandLink id="editCommandLinkId"                                               
                action="#{countryBean.editCountryByCountryCode(countryLang.countryCode,true)}" title="Edit" styleClass="edit_icon" onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>

        </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

suppose I edited for US, then it will show data for AU like that.
for sorting I am using belwo technique

```
private ArrayList<Country> myexistingCountryList;
public String getInitList() {
    myexistingCountryList= getExistingCountryList();
    return null;
}


public ArrayList<Country> getExistingCountryList() {



        try {
            existingCountryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            existingCountryList.addAll(getCountryService().getExistingCountry());


        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorLogger.error("Error while getExistingCountryList in service layer", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are to many mistakes in your code.

Instead of `$` use `#`

Instead of `sortBy="countryName"` write `sortBy="#{countryLang.countryName}"`

So basicly

change this

```
<p:column width="30%" headerText="Country " sortBy="countryName">
    <h:outputLabel value="${countryLang.countryName}" />
</p:column>
```

to this

```
<p:column width="30%" headerText="Country " sortBy="#{countryLang.countryName}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{countryLang.countryName}" />
</p:column>
```